# Assigning Background Colour to Created Shortcut to Console?

Tags: powershell, console, shortcut, wsh

I have a PowerShell script that creates a new shortcut via Window Scripting Host.

The target is a console program, and I wish to set the "Screen Background" colour, as seen on the "Colors" tab in the properties of an existing console shortcut.

[image: Colors Tab in Shortcut]

I can create the shortcut no problem, and once it's created I can edit the Colors tab and change the background colour as wanted via the GUI.  I just need to figure out a way to set it via the script that creates it (either during creation, or modifying it after creation).

I've examined the WSH CreateShortcut and WshShortcut documentation, but can find nothing about setting those console appearance properties.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is `ColorTable` in `HKCU:\Console\ExampleConsole`

Comment: [Here's where I saw someone using that reg key](http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/11/14/zenburn-powershell)

Comment: @BenH Appreciated, but that seems to be about setting a custom PowerShell console color map, vs. assigning a colour to a command console launched via a shortcut (see the image I added to the question to see what I'm trying to change).

Comment: Both use the same console by default. Try making a PowerShell shortcut and selecting `Properties`->`Colors`, you will see the same settings.

Comment: @BenH Ok I continued ot examine it, but it seems that approach requires manually fiddling with the appearance properties to make them "stick" to the LNK.  "At this point there will be a new shortcut on the desktop called Zenburn PowerShell (or whatever name was chosen). Change a few properties on the shortcut, like font and window size (Consolas 16px looks great). Then..." :(

Comment: hmm, here's some lower-level stuff: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774916(v=vs.85).aspx, and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773359(v=vs.85).aspx  Not sure how/if I can implement them in PS (or .Net or alike).

Comment: Stuff related to that IShellLinkDataList interface, for PS: http://poshcode.org/2493, http://sourcewarp.blogspot.ca/2012/06/windows-powershell-shortcut-ishelllink.html#!/2012/06/windows-powershell-shortcut-ishelllink.html hopefully I (and/or someone else) can come up with something based on that info. :)